# vis.js building a dataset dynamically

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'm working on a project and have a need/desire to use vis.js to display data on a timeline.  But, because of how the data is being captured, I need to build the dataset for the timeline somewhat dynamically when the page loads.  With that in mind, I started experimenting with ways to do this, but have hit a roadblock that is mostly likely due to my own lack of knowledge.

The following is the test code I've been working with (I'm aware it is not the best or cleanest code.  I'm focusing on functionality at the moment, but if you have suggestions for cleaning this up, I'm all ears!)  What I want to do is use the content from the variable **datasetlist** to build the dataset.  But when I simply try to pass that variable to new vis.DataSet, it doesn't build the visualization.  I'd appreciate any guidance anyone may be able to offer.  I was wondering if I needed to transform that variable in some way for vis.js to accept it, but haven't been able to figure out if that is indeed the case, and if so, how.

```
var ERP = "yes";
var ERPDate = "2018";
var CRM = "no";
var CRMDate = "2019";
var IDSeq = 1;
var datasetlist = "";
var yesCount = 0

//count totalitems
if (ERP == "yes") {
    yesCount = (yesCount + 1);
}

if (CRM == "yes") {
    yesCount = (yesCount + 1);
}

//builddataset
if (ERP == "yes"){
    if (yesCount == IDSeq) {
    datasetlist = datasetlist + "{id: " + IDSeq + ", content: \'ERP\', start: \'" + ERPDate + "\'}";
} else {
    datasetlist = datasetlist +  "{id: " + IDSeq + ", content: \'ERP\', start: \'" + ERPDate + "\'},";
}
IDSeq = IDSeq +1
}

if (CRM == "yes"){
    if (yesCount == IDSeq) {
    datasetlist = datasetlist + "{id: " + IDSeq + ", content: \'CRM\', start: \'" + CRMDate + "\'}";
} else {
    datasetlist = datasetlist +  "{id: " + IDSeq + ", content: \'CRM\', start: \'" + CRMDate + "\'},";
}
}

//datasetlist = "{id: 1, content: 'ERP', start: '2018'}"
//window.alert(datasetlist);

      // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
      var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

      // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
      var items = new vis.DataSet(datasetlist);

      // Configuration for the Timeline
      var options = {
    height: '500px',
      start: new Date(2015, 1, 15),
      end: new Date(2025, 1, 15),
      timeAxis: {scale: 'year', step: 1}
  };

      // Create a Timeline
      var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Vis expects an array of items as the dataset. Something like this,`var data = new vis.DataSet([data])` where `[data]` is an array of objects. So try building your objects and pushing them into an array and then pass that in as the data parameter. The documentation can be found here http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html.